# How to take input in Java this way?

Tags: java, input

I want to take the inputs for the length, breadth and height of my "Box" class repectively. Now I want to take it as a stream of integers and then set them individually to each of the dimension of the box. The stream will be taken as i/p until the user presses 0. So I wrote it this way (I am just mentioning the main method, I defined the box class seperately):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    System.out .print("Enter length, breadth and height->> (Press '0' to end the i/p)");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while((br.read())==0)
    {
        // What should I write here to take the input in the required manner?
    }
}
```

PS: I cannot use `scanner`, `console` or `DataInputStream`. So help me here with `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Can you use `readLine()`? This will read data from user as String. To parse String to integer you can use `Integer.parseInt(yourString)`.

Comment: @Pshemo, Yes, of course I can. I just need a method to acqire the result using `BufferedReader`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you indicated you absolutely must use the `BufferedReader`, I believe one way to do this is to use the `BufferedReader#readLine()` method instead. That will give you the full line as entered by the user, up to the line termination (either a '\r' or '\n' according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)).

As Zong Zheng Li already said, while the `Scanner` class can tokenize the input line for you, since you cannot use that, you'll have to do that yourself manually.

At this moment, one way that springs to mind is to simply split on a space (\s) character. So your code might look something like this:

```
System.out .print("Enter length, breadth and height->> (Press '0' to end the i/p)");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String inputLine = br.readLine(); // get user input

String[] inputParts = inputLine.split("\\s+"); // split by spaces

int width = Integer.parseInt(inputParts[0]);
int height = Integer.parseInt(inputParts[1]);
int breadth = Integer.parseInt(inputParts[2]);
```

*Note that I'm not showing any error or range checking, or input validation, as I'm just showing a general example.*

I'm sure there's plenty of other ways to do this, but this is the first idea that popped in my mind. Hope it helps somewhat.

Comment: Also, for some reason I seem to think you want to accept the input in one single line, which is why I'm showing that string splitting bit. If I've misunderstood that, please let me know.

Comment: One thing I forgot to ask how is the code `String[] inputParts = inputLine.split("\\s+");` splitting the string by spaces?

Comment: @Mistu4u the [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method takes a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). The `\s+` is matching one or more blank spaces, and the method splits based on that/those match(es). Note the second slash (`\\s+`) is required in Java (and many other languages) to escape the first slash since the slash is a escape character with [a specific meaning to the compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular reason you're not just using [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)? It tokenizes and parses values for you:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int width = sc.nextInt();
int height = sc.nextInt();
```

Comment: Yes for particular reason I am not using scanner. I have to do it using "BufferedReader".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String input = 0;
    ArrayList<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();
    boolean exit = true;
    System.out.print("Enter length, breadth and height->> (Press '0' to end the i/p)");
    try {
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       while((input = br.readLine()!=null && exit)
       { 
         StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(input);
         while(t.hasMoreToken()){
             if(Integer.parseInt(t.nextToken()) != 0){
                list.add(input);
             }
             else{
                exit = false;
             }
         }

       }
       //list contains your needs. 
    } catch(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that at minimum it will need to handle spaces? How else will you delimit the digits of the different values?